# SvelteKit doesnt work - src\app.html does not exist issue

Tags: npm, svelte, sveltekit

I'm installed SvelteKit but when I'm trying "npm run dev" I'm getting an error:

src\app.html does not exist
at validate_template
at load_config
at async get_config
at async

But in my src folder I have app.html file! :/ What's wrong?

Answer (score -2):

When you start sveltkit app first you write

```
npm init svelte@next my-app
```

in your terminal,
next, this is very important you go to your app that you have created:

```
cd my-app
```

then you install all dependencies in "my-app":

```
npm install
```

and then you run your server in in "my-app":

```
npm run dev
```